# Flash Builder hanging when attempting to embed fonts

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder, flash-builder4.5

It seems when I try to include a CSS stylesheet that has embedded fonts Flash Builder 4.7 hangs. It usually makes it to 87% or 94%. I have no clue what it could be. Any pointers would help.

Update: I 've removed almost all of the fonts. Now it's getting stuck at 31%.

Update 2: It may have been related to embedding a certain font. I reduced it down to using only two embedded fonts and removed the last one added. It seems to be compiling now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was hanging on a specific font. I removed the font and it is building much faster now. I also limited the number of characters by setting the unicode range:

```
@font-face {
   src: url("/assets/fonts/myfont.ttf");
   fontFamily: myfont;
   embedAsCFF: true;
   fontWeight: normal;
   fontStyle:  normal;
   unicodeRange: U+0020-007E;
}
```